# No CollaboratorJoinedEvent in Google Realtime after CollaboratorLeftEvent triggered by inactivity

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

In the Google Realtime API, a CollaboratorLeftEvent is triggered for the local user after a period of inactivity. However on wakeup, or subsequent activity, there appears to be no ColaboratorJoinedEvent triggered.

Is this a Realtime bug, or is there perhaps an expected/recommended way to deal with this behavior? Should a CollaboratorLeftEvent be ignored if it's for the local user (ie Collaborator.isMe == true)?

Comment: What do you mean by a period of inactivity?  The user should only leave when you close the document or the user closes the tab.

Comment: @Cheryl I get them when for instance I walk away to brew some (more) coffee. Most likely when the laptop sleeps, but I'm fairly sure it's happened when I've just ignored the browser for a long time. When I come back, the console shows a bunch of calls Realtime has made meanwhile, something to do with binds or binding, and at some point, my CollaboratorLeftEvent handler has been fired. By definition it's a little slow to debug this...

Comment: Is it possible that you aren't refreshing the oauth tokens properly?  What browser/os do you see this on?

Comment: @Cheryl It's absolutely possible I'm not doing _anything_ properly... However, currently when my token expires and generates an error, I'm successfully refreshing it. I'll let it sit this evening and post a couple of messages. I'm running/testing on most Win7-compatible browsers, though mostly Chrome, and I believe that's where I've seen it.

Comment: I wasn't able to repro on my mac/chrome with realtime playground.  Mac went to sleep, when I came back it didn't appear that leave had been invoked. Can you repro there?

Comment: @Cheryl I've tried just ignoring it if it's 'me', and the object hasn't been invalidated in any way when I come back to it; all works fine... I'll try to catch it, and if I can find reproducible steps, I'll post them. I'd assume at this point it's solely my issue in some way - likely my natural incompetence.

Comment: Ok, it is possible that there is an issue here.  Detecting browser closing is not straightforwards, and each browser handles things a little differently.

Comment: @CherylSimon Something changed recently? Now I occasionally get a CollaboratorLeftEvent with an undefined collaborator (I'm absolutely not complaining, I don't even feel guilty ignoring these ones...)

Comment: Not on purpose.. We'll look into it. Do you have repro steps?

Comment: No repro steps, but I'll see if I can trap one.